# Extremely slow upload speeds in nautilus with FTP

Tags: nautilus, ftp, wordpress

I was at home uploading a WP site and it's maxing at 4.2kb. I did a speed test and im getting ~1MB upload (my home ISP caps it out at that). I uploaded a 5MB file via Chrome, to test, and it uploaded within 2 mins. The file uploaded was a wordpress.xml file through the uploader. Same file in nautilus is taking forever. To upload this WP site and all the plugins took 1 hour.

Any ideas of why or how?

P.S. I've been using my hosting company also for years and they've never had any speed issues uploading.

Comment: Have you tried uploading using the plain text mode ftp just to be sure it's really nautilus related ?

Comment: What do you mean plain text FTP? Like, through terminal?

Comment: Did you try to set your MTU to a smaller value? SFTP didn't work for me, so I set mine to 1492. You can find your maximal value with ping -s 1464 google.com (try increasing, decrasing 1462; the number in the brackets, when you still get a response, is your new MTU)

Comment: How do I got about changing my MTU?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.